# Ускорение ввода/вывода в с++

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Ситуация такова: имеется код на *с++* для решения некторой задачи. При отправке решения в систему-проверяльщик, один из тестов таймлимитится. Причем сразу на вводе данных. Я полез гуглить, как ускорить ввод данных (из файла) в плюсах, накопал статью про `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` Но, проблема в том, что при запуске кода компилятор *(Codeblocks с mingw 64)*, выдает ошибку. Вопрос: почему вылетает ошибка и как это исправить? Код и скрины прилагаются.

**ФРАГМЕНТ КОДА**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);    //   FILES
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout); // ASSIGNMENTS
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);

    // INPUT //
    cin >> n; 
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Скрин с ашипкай]

Comment: Не верится 1. в то, что ввод является лимитирующим. Очень не верится! И 2. вы привели явно не минимальный самодостаточный пример. Почему мы должны считать, что у вас все сыпется именно на строке ввода? У вас-то явно куда бОльшая программа.

Comment: @Harry, 1. зря не верится.

Comment: Ну вот почему бы не взять и не переписать всё на `scanf`?

Comment: @Harry, программа, естественно, больше. Но, при удалении конкретно данной части, компилится все на ура. Поэтому логично было преддположить, что я что-то не так делаю, удаляя синхру с `cstdio`

Comment: @Qwertiy, думал .как вариант. Но мне интересен конкретно разбор данной проблемы. Но Ваше предложение я попробую воплотить

Comment: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/5217?locale=ru - тут говорится, что freopen (теоретически) может не работать с  отключенной синхронизацией.

Comment: @Qwertiy, возможно.. сейчас попробую

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67278/discussion-between-niklex-and-qwertiy).